# How to mock getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject()?

Tags: spring, mockito

I successfully mocked

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject();
```

with

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTwitterDao.SQL_SELECT_TWITTER, parameterizedRowMapper, 1)).thenReturn(expectedObject);
```

Would you please let me know how to mock

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject();
```

I don't know which object I should mock.

Comment: Hey should really not mock types you don't own, in your case especially JDBC stuff. Write instead an integration test!

Comment: Thanks Brice.  I realized it after posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `JdbcDaoSupport` as the base class to get the template, you can simply construct your DAO in the test and immediately `setJdbcTemplate(mockJdbcTemplate)` on it to replace it with your mock.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for how to mock variable length parameter methods:

Assuming your DAO class also implements RowMapper interface for mocking method `queryForObject(string,rowMapper,Object...)`

```
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(yourDao, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplateMock);
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplateMock.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(dao.getClass()) ,Mockito.anyVararg())).thenReturn(entity);
```