# Mocking getJdbcTemplate method

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

**My scenario is as below:**

I have `no setter methods` in **SampleDao** interface and `no direct field` in **SampleDaoImpl** class

reference: [How to mock getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280774/how-to-mock-getjdbctemplate-queryforobject)

```
public interface SampleDao {
    // some methods
}

public class SampleDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements SampleDao {
    // implementation of some methods
    public String someMethod(String param1, String param2){
        // .....//
        List<String> data = getJdbcTemplate().query(.....);  // -> getJdbcTemplate() is the method of JdbcDaoSupport to get JdbcTemplate
    }
}
```

I want to mock result of `getJdbcTemplate().query(.....)` where `getJdbcTemplate()` is of `JdbcDaoSupport` class which is extended by `SampleDaoImpl`, no where by `SampleDao`.

**My Test case is as below:**

Created object of **SampleDaoImpl** and assigned to **SampleDao**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MockSampleDao {

    String param1 = "", param2 = "";
    @Mock
    SampleDao sampleDao = new SampleDaoImpl();


    public MockSampleDao(String param1, String param2) {
        super();
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;   
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection primeNumbers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
            { "test1", "test1" },
            { "test2", "test2" }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod(){
        try {
        // HOW TO MOCK THE RESULT FROM getJdbcTemplate().query() HERE

            sampleDao.someMethod(param1, param2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the JdbcDaoSupport get the value that it returns from getJdbcTemplate()? Maybe you can mock objects that are osed for generating that jdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 3):

You are mocking the wrong object. You are trying to test `SampleDaoImpl.someMethod()`, so you must create a *concrete* `SampleDaoImpl` instance, not a mocked one.

Once you have a concrete instance, you can then call `setJdbcTemplate()` and pass in a *mocked* `JdbcTemplate` object. Finally, you can control the behaviour of that mock so that when `query()` is invoked by `someMethod()`, your preferred data is returned.

For example:

```
public class MockSampleDao {

    // parameterized stuff omitted for brevity

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {

      SampleDaoImpl impl = new SampleDaoImpl();
      JdbcTemplate template = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
      List<String> someList = // populate this list
      when(template.query(....)).thenReturn(someList);

      impl.setJdbcTemplate(template);
      impl.someMethod(param1, param2);

      // further testing etc.
    }

}
```

Comment: (+1) As a work-around I did like below, similar to what u said. But posted for better approach.

@Mock
SampleDaoImpl sampleDao = new SampleDaoImpl();

Comment: @NamingException I don't understand that comment. You should not be mocking `SampleDaoImpl` at all.

Comment: Sorry, edited the comment. By creating object for SampleDaoImple, I can directly mock the getJdbcTemplate(), as it is extending JdbcDaoSupport class

Comment: @NamingException I suppose that approach would work too. But I would always prefer to avoid mocking my class under test where possible - it's confusing at first glance. It's entirely avoidable in this case, thanks to the handy `setJdbcTemplate()` method.

Answer (score -1):

It should look like this (adjust the mock according to what query API of [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) you want to override ):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MockSampleDao extends SampleDaoImpl{
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

     @Override
     protected JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        return jdbcTemplate;
     }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod(){
        try {
             when(jdbcTemplate.query(/* put here the api that you want to overload*/)).
             thenReturn(/* the mock output that you want */);

            sampleDao.someMethod(param1, param2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: sampleDao.getJdbcTemplate() is not possible as i mentioned in very first. getJdbcTemplate() is no where related to interface SampleDao... As a work-around I already did with mocking SampleDaoImpl as mentioned by @Duncan. But looking for better approach.

Comment: @NamingException Can try something else - extend from `SampleDaoImpl` and override `getJdbcTemplate` method. that's because your class is have more than 1 "role" - it's `JdbcDaoSupport` & `SampleDao` - if you add method in your interface `getDao` will solve your problem

Comment: -1: extending the test class is not the right approach.

Comment: @Duncan I think there are cases when it's the right thing to do. I update the comment above - in this case when `SampleDao` does not give accessto the doa - I think this the way to go. updating the interface will eliminate the need to extend the test class. Also in unit test you want to test `protected` method